# cannot convert from system.linq.iqueryable to system.linq.parallelquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I use to convert query from oracle database to query linq, but I get error. `cannot convert from system.linq.iqueryable to system.linq.parallelquery`. Can you help me to fix the problem. 
this is my query oracle

```
select kd_supp
from
(
select kd_supp
from
(
SELECT 
    KD_SUPP, NPWP_SUPP, 1 seq
FROM TAX.MPMISTAX_MSTSUPP
UNION 
(
    SELECT 
    b.KD_DLR KD_SUPP, b.DLR_NPWP2 NPWP_SUPP, 2 seq
    FROM MPMIS_MSTDEALER b 
    WHERE b.dlr_status<>'C' AND
    DLR_NPWP2 IS NOT NULL
)
) a
    where
    NPWP_SUPP = '016430472629001'
    order by seq desc
)
where
rownum <=1
```

and this is I try to convert to linq,

```
(from data in MpmistaxMstsupps
join kd_supp in MpmisMstdealerView on
    new {kd = data.KdSupp} equals new {kd = kd_supp.KdDlr} into join_kode_supp
    from result_kd in join_kode_supp.DefaultIfEmpty()
join npwp_supp in MpmisMstdealerView on
    new {npwp = data.NpwpSupp} equals new {npwp = npwp_supp.DlrNpwp2} into join_npwp_supp
    from result_npwp in join_npwp_supp.DefaultIfEmpty()
where data.NpwpSupp == "016430472629001"
select new {
    KdSupp = result_kd.KdDlr,
    NpwpSupp = result_npwp.DlrNpwp2})
.Concat(
from data in MpmistaxMstsupps
join kd_supp in MpmisMstdealerView on
    new {kd = data.KdSupp} equals new {kd = kd_supp.KdDlr} into join_kode_supp
    from result_kd in join_kode_supp.DefaultIfEmpty()
join npwp_supp in MpmisMstdealerView on
    new {npwp = data.NpwpSupp} equals new {npwp = npwp_supp.DlrNpwp2} into join_npwp_supp
    from result_npwp in join_npwp_supp.DefaultIfEmpty()
where result_kd.DlrStatus != "C" && result_npwp.DlrNpwp2 != null
select new { 
    result_kd.KdDlr, result_npwp.DlrNpwp2
})
```

and I get error in `concat`. I hope you can help my problem??
[image]

Comment: You're trying to concatenate two queries of different types... you can't do that. They _must_ be the same types.

Comment: when I use `union`, it the same problem

Comment: _They **must** be the same types._

Comment: and, what must I do? you have a solution to describe query linq?

Comment: Take a look at the two `select new { ... }` statements. They generate different anonymous types and `Concat` requires them to be the same. I guess in this case simply copy/paste the first select over the second will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help to describe my problem. I have found my problem.